# is it possible to use the mjsip stack for IM in java

Tags: java

Hello I would like to create a program that is based on the SIP protocol an let the users chat with each other using IM. I would like to use MJSIP is this possible using this stack I know that can be done using jain-sip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

["MjSip is a complete java-based implementation of a SIP stack"](http://www.mjsip.org/)

so yes.